# How can I remove posts from a Facebook Fan page?

Tags: facebook

I've really few experience with Facebook development, just made few things...

I'd like to know how to programatically modify a fan page, the particular requirement that I've right now is to control posts from users, I'd like to be notified for a new post and also have the ability to delete posts.

Could you guide me to accomplish this task? What should I use / read to get this done.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is now way to receive an email through facebook when someone adds a new wall post to a Fan Page.

Follow this thread:

http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=6802152230&topic=9913#topic_top

A user did mention "If you're using Firefox, install Update Scanner to your addons"

I'm sure the docs can help you on programmatically deleting a post. Try here:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.remove